# Change innerHTML with a parameter

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I try to change a paragraph by hovering over it.

HTML

```
<p id="foo"> Hello world! </p>
```

Javascript

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener("mouseover", ChangeText("Goodbye world!"));

function ChangeText(s) {
    this.innerHTML = s;
}
```

Yet the paragraph doesn't change on hover. When the parameter is left out and the string is directly typed like below it does work. Why?

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener("mouseover", ChangeText);

function ChangeText() {
    this.innerHTML = "Goodbye world!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The addEventListener wants a function as a second argument; so, if you call a function with an argument, you might write :

```
foo.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        ChangeText("Goodbye world!",event.target)
     });

function ChangeText(s,target) {
    target.innerHTML = s;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work for me.

Comment: The `this` value doesn't refer the `foo`. You can either update `ChangeText` to set `foo.innerHTML` or use the [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to invoke the function with `this` set to `foo` (`ChangeText.call(foo, "Goodbye world!")`).